# Kalam Cosmological Argument

Tags: sources-mekorot, creation, rishonim, hashkafah-philosophy

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kal%C4%81m_cosmological_argument#cite_ref-4) writes:

> The Kalām cosmological argument is a variation of the cosmological argument that argues for the existence of a first cause for the universe, and the existence of a god. Its origins can be traced to medieval Jewish, Christian and Muslim thinkers, but most directly to Islamic theologians of the Kalām tradition.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kal%C4%81m_cosmological_argument#cite_ref-4) Its historic proponents include John Philoponus,[2] Al-Kindi,[3] **Saadia Gaon**,[4] Al-Ghazali,[5] and St. Bonaventure.[6] William Lane Craig revived interest in the Kalām cosmological argument with his 1979 publication of a book of the same name.[7][8]

The Kalam Cosmological Argument is this (simply): Everything that has a beginning of existence has a cause of existence. The universe has a beginning of existence. Therefore the universe has a cause of existence.

Wikipedia tells me that Rav Saadia wrote this argument. Can anyone tell me where it is in the **Hebrew version?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page numberings there correspond to Treatise 1 ("Concerning the belief that all existing things have been created"), Chapter 1, toward the beginning. If that's not enough information, what Hebrew edition are you working with?

Comment: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/kapah/shaar-2.htm can you show me here?

Comment: @HachamGabriel Note that is a translation from the original Arabic.

Comment: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/kapah/1-2.htm#1

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not so Baki in old arabic.